# How can i do this without "awk" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I want to read a text file with some conditions

```
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 123"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 206"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:19:43:50 +0200] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 377"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /sit-3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 - "
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 375"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /sit3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15811"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 375"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /sit3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15811"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 299"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /sit3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15811"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 299"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /sit3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15811"
111.196.10.2 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 304 299"
111.196.10.3 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 302"
111.196.10.1 - - [20/Jan/2020:07:00:50 +0100] "GET /thttpd_powered_2.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2114"
```

1: I want a script that counts IP addresses in the text file and gives me output like this

```
111.196.10.1  8
111.196.10.2  8
111.196.10.3  7
```

for the above, I have written a script

```
cat file | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

it's properly working but I want this without "awk"

2:my 2nd requirement is, count IP address only when the second last number of the line starts with 2. output will be

```
111.196.10.1  7
111.196.10.3  7
111.196.10.2  5
```

for this, I have written a script

```
grep '^[^"]*"[^"]*" 2' file | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

it's also properly working but I want this without "awk"

Comment: I suggest to do everything with GNU awk.

Comment: Why do you want to do these without `awk`? It's one of the best tools for things like this.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for replying to me, our task is, do this without "awk"

Comment: You could take a look at man cut

Comment: The only legitimate reason to avoid using `awk` is a desire to replace it with `perl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can get only the first column with Cut, then sort the resulting IPs and count them with Uniq.

   ```
   cut -f1 -d' ' file | sort -n | uniq -c
   ```
2. If you only want to count in the line if the second-to-last number starts with a `2`, then just add a Grep.

   ```
   grep -E '2[0-9]* [0-9]+"$' t | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort -n | uniq -c
   ```

Tested on sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Without `awk`.

```
grep -oE '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' Input_file | sort | uniq -c
```

---

---

With `awk`:

Could you please try following, to do it in a single `awk`.

```
awk '
match($1,/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){
  arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

OR if 1st field is only ip address then we need not to mention `substr` in array index we could directly use `$1` like following.

```
awk '
match($1,/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){
  arr[$1]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($1,/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){      ##using match function to match IP address regex in current line.
  arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++    ##Create array arr which has index as sub string of matched regex from RSTART to RLENGTH.
}
END{                                  ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){                    ##Traversing through arr from here.
    print key,arr[key]                ##printing key and array value here.
  }
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` to read two fields from input, then echo them in a different order.

So replace

```
awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

with

```
while read count ip; do
    echo "$ip $count"
done
```

Comment: This particular subscript seems completely useless anyway. If the task is to trim whitespace from the `uniq` output, this will work, but slowly and obscurely. Maybe `sed 's/  */ /g;s/^ //'` where there should be two spaces before the `*`

Comment: For robustness with packslashes, prefer `read -r` (probably not useful here, but should really be the default everywhere in modern scripts).

Comment: I have to object to @tripleee 's proposal that `-r` should be considered best practice.  Instead, tools should honor an escaped newline and `-r` should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @tripleee I thought the task was to swap the order of the fields in `uniq -c` output.